# Como cambiar el cursor en determinado punto en Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Necesito hacer que el cursor cambie mientras esta ejecutando una tarea en especifico, devolverlo a su normalidad cuando termine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay una funcion en [esta](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Cursor_-_Change_the_mouse_cursor_of_WizardForm) pagina.
Aqui la funcion:

```
procedure SetControlCursor(control: TWinControl; cursor: TCursor);
var i:Integer;
    wc: TWinControl;
begin
  if (not (control = nil)) then begin
    control.Cursor := cursor;
    try
      for i:=0 to control.ControlCount-1 do begin
        wc := TWinControl(control.Controls[i]);
        if (NOT(wc = nil)) then
          SetControlCursor(wc, cursor)
        else
          control.Controls[i].Cursor := cursor;
      end; {for}
    finally

    end;{try}
  end;{if}
end;{procedure SetControlCursor}
```

Llamas de esta manera:

```
  SetControlCursor(WizardForm, crHourGlass);
```

Para volver al normal:

```
  SetControlCursor(WizardForm, crDefault);
```